# how to pass an array (not list) into a java method from groovy?

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

My code in Groovy is following:

```
def derivateTypeArray = [136L, 185L ] as long[];
apl.set( ConverterAction.Parameter.derivateTypeIds, derivateTypeArray);
```

Back in Java I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [J
    at 
[...]
```

How can I make sure that it is an aarray of long and not an `ArrayList` when I pass the derivateTypeArray to a Java method?

Comment: Which part of code throws `ClassCastException`? What version of Groovy you use? I can't see what may cause the issue in the code you shown to us.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak I actually followed your [deleted] answer and it has worked so far. it was java that threw the exception.